# If $f(z)$ is even then residue at $z=z_0$ is zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, residue-calculus

There is a theorem in my text book which says that:

> *Theorem*:If $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$ and if $f$ is even in $z-z_0$ i.e $f(z-z_0)=f(-(z-z_0))$ then Res$[f(z),z_0]=0$ [Theorem 8.60, page 290,S ponnusami]

> *My doubt*: let $f(z)$ be even function then $f(z)=f(-z)$ for all $z$ in domain of f and hence we have $f(w)=f(-w)$ where $w=z-z_0$ implying that $f$ is even in $z-z_0$ and hence from theorem for any even function $f$ Res$[f(z),z_0]=0$ at isolated singularity $z_0$ which I think wrong.For counter example see the picture added [image]

Comment: I guess that "$f$ even in $z-z_0$" means $f(z-z_0)=f(-z-z_0)$ for every $z$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe but I guess "$f$ even in $z−z_0$" means  f(z-z₀) is even function of z,what do you say?

Comment: @lbs Yes, this is what I say, but this is not the definition given in your theorem.

Comment: So I think statement of theorem is wrong, right?

Comment: @lbs Yes, since you found a counterexample to it, it must be wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

The theorem requires that the function be even about the point $z_0$. The function $\frac{1}{z \sin z}$ is even about $z=0$, but it is not even about $z=\pi$. Indeed, the residue at $z=0$ is in fact $0$, but not the residue at $z=\pi$.

Comment: what do you mean by " $f$ to be even about $z_0$? Secondly don't you think what author defines even in $z-z_0$ is wrong?

Comment: then why $\frac{1}{z \sin z}$ is not even about $z=\pi$,I can't understand,please let me know,it is easy calculation which says that f is even about z=π if the definiting criteria is same as you defined it

Comment: Ok, let's see. We want the function $f(z)$ to be even in the variable $w=z-z_0$. We therefore set $z=w+z_0$ and impose $f(w+z_0)=f(-w+z_0)$. This is equivalent to $f(z)=f(-z+2z_0)$.

Comment: So equivalently can i say  "f even in z−z0" means f(z-z₀) is even function of z,what do you say?

Comment: Yes, the statement of the theorem is actually incorrect

Answer (score -1):

I think what you've gotten wrong is the theorem itself. When faced with a statement you doubt, I recommend looking for easy examples before you try and prove it. Here, I can think of the function:

$$f(z)= \frac{1}{z^2-1}$$
It is clearly even, since $ f(z)=f(-z) $. If we calculate the residue of f in $z_0=1$, we get:
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow1}{f(z)·(z-1)}=\lim_{z\rightarrow1}{\frac{1}{z+1}}=\frac{1}{2}\neq0 $$
If a function is even, it will have a singularity at $z_0$ if and only if it has it at $-z_0$, and the residues of $f$ will be the same.

Comment: You are mistaken. Your $f(z)$ is even about the point $z=0$, so it is at this point that you should compute the residue